# constrain param type by previous param type without string indexing

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Define a function `fn(a,b)` that can accept the following arrangement of arguments:

- `(a: number, b: array)`
- `(a: boolean, b: object)`

```
fn(1, [ ]) // valid
fn(true, { }) // valid

fn(1, { }) // invalid
fn(true, [ ]) //invalid

// The type of `b` is dependent on the type of `a` such that
// if a is a `number` then `b` must be an `array`
// and if `a` is a `boolean` then `b` must be an `object`
```

*without* the use of `string` literal indexing, e.g

```
interface TypeMap {
    number: array
    boolean: object
}

function fn<T extends keyof TypeMap>(a: number | boolean, discriminator: T, b: TypeMap[T]) { }

fn(1, 'number', [ ])
fn(true, 'boolean', { })

// this implementation is not satisfactory
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *at least* two ways, here.

Simplest is just [function overloads.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
function fn(a: number, b: unknown[]): unknown
function fn(a: boolean, b: Record<string, unknown>): unknown

function fn(
    a: number | boolean,
    b: unknown[] | Record<string, unknown>
) {
    //...
}

fn(1, [ ]) // valid
fn(true, { }) // valid

fn(1, { }) // invalid
fn(true, [ ]) // invalid
```

You simply have one signature per pair, and your implementation handle all possibilities.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAhgLkWEBbAIwFMAnAGkQO3AGsw4B3MAbQF0BKasOxsAKFCRYCZGiyU4cADZF0YClUQAlIhDgkAJgB4AzlBIwwAcwq16TAHydEZ3nwHho8JClR9EHxONyFSiAD4S0rLy7p6KtkxsAcqq6tp6Bsam3OZgFnzsiADeYR4A9PkAdCV8AL72rgCMFMyIHIiFiABu6FIwGgJo+iBEFNmIZVlNre2dXag1OYPD+YiGox0TPX2IdQ2FC21LfEA)

---

Or you could define a union of parameter tuple types like so:

```
type TypeMap =
    | [a: number, b: unknown[]]
    | [a: boolean, b: Record<string, unknown>]

function fn(...[a, b]: TypeMap) {
    //...
}

fn(1, [ ]) // valid
fn(true, { }) // valid

fn(1, { }) // invalid
fn(true, [ ]) // invalid
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4BQVtQD5QG0kAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaKG0isgazIHsB3MggF1BWHPiKka3bgBsISMs1ZQAShADG3egBMAPAGdg9AJZkA5s3Zc+ZAHwiMAM3brgx7mSiOyACgB0AURKgqRwkMhgAJRQAN6i2AD0CQF+GAC+GE6+AIzMBFCC0UlQAG5IMsbaWT5GFBDMMVBpRQml5ZWZ3j65sU0tUKZlFVVdtfWEBS2D7VUYQA)